# Effectively handling python exceptions raised from __enter__ when resource is unavailable

Tags: python, resources, with-statement

I want to manage a resource via `with`, but I'm having problems to handle the exception when this resource is unavailable. My resource is a [FileLock](https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock) mechanism that avoids collisions between processes running in parallel when writing output to a csv file. My code reads like this:

```
data_not_to_lost  # this is a dataframe
with FileLock('database.csv'):
    data_not_to_lost.to_csv('database.csv')
```

The problem I have is that sometimes the resource is unavailable. When this happens, `FileLock` raises an exception from its `__enter__` method. This makes that the main code inside the `with` block is not executed (neither is the `__exit__` method called, as far as I understood).

My solution to this problem is wrap the whole environment in a `try`...`except` couple like this:

```
    data_not_to_lost  # this is a dataframe
    try:
        with FileLock('database.csv'):
            data_not_to_lost.to_csv('database.csv')
    except FileLockException:
        data_not_to_lost.to_csv('backup.csv')
```

This solution seems to work, but it reads ugly and most likely an anti pattern because:

1. The code inside the `with` (which in my actual implementation is larger) has to be repeated in two different parts, therefore being a magnet for bugs.
2. I had understood that a great deal about `with` is to avoid chaining `try` ... `except` clauses at multiple levels. Currently I need two levels (which to some extent is annoying because my code is already very indented and sticking to 80 characters per line is becoming a pain).

Am I missing anything? Is my "solution" the correct way to handle the exception raised when the resource is unavailable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had understood that a great deal about with is to avoid chaining try ... except clauses at multiple levels.

Not my understanding and I have never heard or read this to be an intrinsic function of context managers. Their purpose is to manage resources.
[PyMOTW](https://pymotw.com/2/contextlib/) puts it nicely:

> A context manager is responsible for a resource within a code block, possibly creating it when the block is entered and then cleaning it up after the block is exited.

The resource that the `FileLock` manages is the lock file to try to ensure exclusive access to a file. It can 'tell' when you can't get that exclusive access, but it's up to you to handle such cases.
You can try to increase the [timeout](https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock/blob/master/filelock/filelock.py#L15-L16) on the `FileLock`, but ultimately you need a strategy for a timeout when trying to acquire the lock.

> The code inside the with (which in my actual implementation is larger) has to be repeated in two different parts, therefore being a magnet for bugs.

I understand that the code in your question is just a stripped down example, but if you are rightfully reluctant to repeat code portions, is there no chance to move that to a function that you can parametrize depending on whether the lock can be acquired or not?

```
def do_stuff(filename):
    data_not_to_lost.to_csv(filename)

try:
    with FileLock('database.csv'):
        do_stuff('database.csv')
except FileLockException:
    do_stuff('backup.csv')
```

Comment: Ok, so then you would say that my current approach is the pythonic way to tackle the situation, so I'm not misusing the with environment, right?

Comment: Absolutely. Can't see anything wrong with how you are doing this.